# can't receive server full response

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I'm using *Java Socket Programming* in order to receive server responses, I'm using a `char array` and read each response in it using `read()` method:

```
InputStream stream = null;
try{
    stream = socket.getInputStream();
}catch(Exception e){
    conn_lost();
}

if(stream != null){
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    stream));

Looper.prepare();
char a[] = new char[1000];
for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++){
      a[i] = ' ';
   }

while (true){

   input.read(a);

   String response = String.valueOf(a);

   process_server_response(response);

   for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++){
         a[i] = ' ';
      }
}
```

The problem is **some times** I can't receive the full response from the server and instead of that I receive like half of it and then the response after that I receive the other half.

**Worth to mention:**

**1-** the affected response is a little large that other responses but I'm sure it's not exceed **1000** litters.

**2-** I'm pretty sure the server-side works perfectly and it sends the responses completed.

**3-** there isn't any type of **terminators** exist which could cause that behavior.

Comment: You needn't fill the buffer (`a`) with spaces. `input.read(a)` returns the number of `char`s that were read. If you save this number to a variable, you can use [`String.valueOf(char[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char:A-int-int-) to convert the buffer data to a string. That should increase performance.

Comment: @fabian well, thanks a lot, that really was bothering me and I didn't think before about using the retrieved number of chars. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is some times I can't receive the full response from the server and instead of that I receive like half of it and then the response after that I receive the other half.

Yes. That's how stream protocols work. You shouldn't assume that you'll receive all the data in a single call to `read()`.

If you have multiple messages on the same stream, you'll need a way of telling where a message ends. You *must not* rely on `read()` reading the whole of one message but not reading any of the next message.

The three common approaches are:

- A length prefix for each message
- A separator between messages
- Self-terminating messages (e.g. XML, where you can tell the end of a document by reaching its closing tag)

If you don't have any of those schemes in place, but you want to put multiple messages on the wire and process them separately, your protocol is fundamentally broken and you should revisit it.

Additionally, you should specify the encoding to apply when constructing the `InputStreamReader`. Don't just use the platform default.

Comment: by the way, in your opinion what's the best encoding to apply when I receive Json responses?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat: Well, if you're able to work in a binary format with the text within it, I'd UTF-8 encode the JSON, and have a simple length prefix. I'm a big fan of length prefixes, in terms of letting the client know exactly how much data to read, without it depending on the content. It does depend on you controlling both the client and the server though.